# Exporting automated value to excel file in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using selenium webdriver in eclipse with Java for a project at work. I am in need of exporting a value to an excel file. I am able to write to an excel file but am unable to export the specific value to the excel file.

Here is the automation process for getting the value:

```
public void AbbeyNational (String AbbeyNationalURL, String AN_AccCookiesButton, String AN_MortgageTabButton, String AN_ExistingCustomerButton, String AN_FollowRateButton, String AN_SVRButton, String AN_RateFld)throws InterruptedException {

    driver.get(AbbeyNationalURL);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(AN_AccCookiesButton)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText(AN_MortgageTabButton)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(AN_ExistingCustomerButton)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(AN_FollowRateButton)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(AN_SVRButton)).click();
    String a = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(AN_RateFld)).getText();
    String AN_Rate = a.substring(54,58);
    System.out.println(AN_Rate);
}
```

The 'AN_Rate' variable holds the value after automation.
The value prints to the console but I need the value to be exported to the excel file with the use of automation. Can anyone help me with this?

Additionally, here is my code for writing to an excel file:

```
public void writeToExcel(String AN_Rate) throws IOException{
    File file = new File(filePath+"\\"+fileName);
    XSSFWorkbook IRWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet Sheet0 = IRWorkbook.createSheet();
    Sheet0.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue(AN_Rate);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        IRWorkbook.write(fos);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code for large set of data :

```
public class ExcelWriter {

// LinkedHashMap to maintain the insertion order
public static Map<String, String> dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
public static String filePath = "D:\\ECLIPSE-WORKSPACE\\playground\\src\\main\\resources";
public static String fileName = "demo-data";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String AN_Rate = "Data-1";
    String BN_Rate = "Data-2";
    String CN_Rate = "Data-3";

    dataMap.put("AN_Rate", AN_Rate);
    dataMap.put("BN_Rate", BN_Rate);
    dataMap.put("CN_Rate", CN_Rate);

    writeToExcel(dataMap, filePath, fileName);
}

public static void writeToExcel(Map<String, String> dataMap, String filePath, String fileName) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filePath + "\\" + fileName + ".xlsx");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    file.createNewFile();
    XSSFWorkbook IRWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = IRWorkbook.createSheet();
    List<String> headers = dataMap.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList()); // all key values in a list
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>(dataMap.values()); // all data in a list

    setHeadersAndFillData(sheet, headers, data); // filling excel sheet with headers and corresponding data

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        IRWorkbook.write(fos);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void setHeadersAndFillData(XSSFSheet sheet, List<String> headers, List<String> data) {
    int headersSize = headers.size();
    int dataSize = headers.size();
    Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
    Row dataRow = sheet.createRow(1);
    setCells(headers, headersSize, headerRow);
    setCells(data, dataSize, dataRow);
}

private static void setCells(List<String> cellData, int headersSize, Row row) {
    for (int rn = 0; rn < headersSize; rn++) {
        row.createCell(rn).setCellValue(cellData.get(rn));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi dangi13, thank you for answering my question. However, I am having trouble with the following line of code: 

List<String> headers = dataMap.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

Whenever I import the Collectors.util to my project it outputs a error and prompts me to convert the List from a String to an Object type. Could you help me with this?

Comment: I think you are using JRE 1.7 or below. Please update it to 1.8 to support the stream operation. If you still want to use the same JRE than update the  line : List<String> headers = dataMap.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());   with List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
  headers.addAll(dataMap.keySet());  and than use this headers variable anywhere. It will work for your current JRE. Please do let me know if that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your method writeToExcel with :

Replace :`File file = new File(filePath+"\\"+fileName);`
 with added file extention

```
 File file = new File(filePath+"\\"+fileName + ".xlsx");
```

and than the value will be exported to excel file.

And if there is large set of data than you should store all values in a static map and than export all values to excel at once.